# Eclipse - Java Template - static import - Template variable '' has incompatible types

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a Java code template (Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates) for a JUnit4 test method that should also include a static import to use some hamcrest matchers.

```
${:importStatic('org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*')}
${:import(org.junit.Test)}
@Test
public void ${testName}() throws Exception {    
    ${cursor} 
}
```

I am not able to save the code template - an error message is shown:

> Template variable '' has incompatible types.

It works fine with either import statement, so the syntax seems to be correct.

How can I combine the two import statements to work together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
${imp:import(org.junit.Test)}
${impst:importStatic('org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*')}

@Test
public void ${testName}() throws Exception {    
    ${cursor} 
}
```

edit: If I recall correctly the first parts acts as the name variable and the second part is the type (import, var, ...). 
For example the following also won't work

```
${:newType(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandItem)}
if (${:var(boolean)}) {
    ${cursor}
} else {

}
```

You could remove imp or impst from my answer and it would also still work. 
In a template you can perform multiple actions on a variable, a good example is the List template.

```
    ${type:newType(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List)} ${list:newName(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List)}= new ${type}(${parent:var(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite)}, ${style:link('SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL', 'SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL', SWT.MULTI, 'SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL', 'SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL', SWT.SINGLE)});
${list}.setLayoutData(new ${gridDataType:newType(org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData)}(SWT.${horizontal:link(FILL, BEGINNING, CENTER, END)}, SWT.${vertical:link(FILL, TOP, CENTER, BOTTOM)}, ${hex:link(true, false)}, ${vex:link(true, false)}));
${list}.setItems(${word_selection}${});
${imp:import(org.eclipse.swt.SWT)}${cursor}
```

Here they are performing multiple operations on the list variable

Comment: I get "Variable 'import' is unknown  error."
I am trying to edit the class body template from Java - Code Style - Code Templates - Code - Class body and trying to add logger with the import statement.

Answer (score 1):

Simons answer worked for me.

The "Help - Eclipse Platform" explains staticimports, it also offers an example. For version Photon you can look over here:

https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm